# How to tab focus on a button like image Component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following `template` in my `vue.js` application:

```
<div>
     <button class="button_text" @click="reset">Reset</button>
     <button class="button_text">Search</button>
     <image-component class="button_image_icon"/>
</div>
```

I am trying to set the tab focus on the `<image-component>` which is not a `<button>` but a `Component` with a `label` and `input` inside a `<span>` . It sets focus on the buttons easily but not sure how to do it on an button like image icon.

**Tried:** `@click="setFocus"`, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it by adding the `tabindex` attribute to all the elements

```
<div>
     <button class="button_text" @click="reset" tabindex="1">Reset</button>
     <button class="button_text" tabindex="2">Search</button>
     <image class="button_image_icon" tabindex="3" />
</div>
```

Example with focus manually set with javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/qeugo6hm/5/

Comment: Hasn't worked. Adding this even lose the previous focus on the buttons.

Comment: Perhaps what I missed could be the issue. The `image` is a `Component` itself. Now updated the problem description.